# Using string part as an alias in Select query

Tags: mysql

How can i use a string part like in this case a two char language string as an alias in an MySQL select query?

This is not working:

```
SELECT i.title AS en, l.title AS LEFT(l.lang, 2)
FROM images AS i
LEFT JOIN images_lang AS l ON l.oid=i.oid
WHERE i.oid = 10
```

Comment: Try researching: [dynamic sql](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dynamic+sql+%5Bmysql%5D+).     A column name is fixed when starting the SQL statement.

Comment: A column can only have one alias, it can't be different depending on the row value.

Comment: Can you show sample data and the desired result?

Comment: You should have that expression as a column value, as opposed to a column title. Column title applies to the entire row, but you seem to want to label individual rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in SQL. An alias must be fixed *before* it starts reading data, and it can only be an identifier, not an expression.

Also a column alias can only have one value for all rows in the query result. It can't be a different alias depending on the data in the rows.

So I would suggest you do the labeling in your client application after you fetch the result.